# How to Reduce Decimal Precision of Image Value in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, spatial-statistics

I'd like to ask about the value on following image.

This is an interpolated precipitation layer using IDW method in ArcGIS Desktop. On this layer, the values is like this:

[image: precipitation layer]

This is a raster image. After exporting the above layer into raster image, the value of the raster image has quite long decimals, specially the minimum value looks like this 4.43193612012e007.

[image: Raster image]

I have not only this image but also several images with similar value. When I calculate any equation on those images, output value from that calculation cannot be accepted, they were totally wrong.

So how can I reduce the decimal precision before or after exporting to raster?

Comment: Could you please describe the calculations you are making?

Comment: Is your problem only the display in the legend of too many decimals? This is the expected output for a interpolation surface

Comment: @Aaron, here is an example of calculations I'm doing in ERDAS model maker.  STACK SUM (( $n2_temp_2000 / 5.0 )  POWER 1.514)

Comment: @A.R. I'm expecting the output with max of 3 decimals. But it is ok even it is the same decimals as interpolated layer.

Comment: you made the IDW in ERDAS or ArcGIS ?

Comment: Try exporting the IDW grid to .img format prior to bringing it into Erdas.

Comment: My some temperature and precipitation images have the same problem with long decimal value. And some of images with min value just 3 or 4 decilmals are ok to calculate the formula. I did interpolation many times over again and again changing the interpolation method. But I didn't get succeed.

Comment: I made interpolation in ARCGIS. Raster image have already been converted to .img format to read it in ERDAS

Comment: Try adding round (stack_sum),3

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try multiplying by a constant and converting to integer. For example, use the [Times](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Times/009z0000009p000000/) tool to multiply by a constant representing the number of decimal places you wish to preserve (e.g. 1000 for three decimal places) and then truncate the remaining decimal values with the [Int](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Int/009z0000008z000000/) tool. Just be sure to remember that the values have been transformed in this way (or go a step further and convert back to a [Float](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Float/009z0000008w000000/) and then [Divide](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Divide/009z0000008r000000/) by the constant).

All functions can be used inside the [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) to make this more efficient.